# "Array subscript is not an integer" in C program

Tags: c

The `deviation` function throws me the following error: `"Array subscript is not an integer"`. If you can help me locate the cause of error I'll appreciate it.

```
float average(float data[], int n) {
    float total = 0;
    float *p = data;

    while (p < (data + n)) {
        total = total + *p;
        p++;
    }

    return total / n;
}

float deviation(float data[], int n) {
    float data_average = average(data, n);
    float total;
    float *p = data;

    while (p < (data + n)) {
        total += (data[p] - data_average) * (data[p + 1] - data_average);
    }

    return total / 2;
}
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. An array subscript has to be an integer. In `datos[p]`, `p` is a pointer, not an integer. You can't do that. (Well, you can do silly things like `5[array]`, but you're not doing that here; `datos` is also a pointer.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, I've never seen the 5[array] syntax. I tried it and it seems the same as array[5], but where/why would one use something like that? Thanks.

Comment: @CharlieBurns; `array[5]` is equivalent to `*(array + 5)` and same for `5[array` which is equal to `*(5 + array)`. That's why `array[5] = 5[array]`. *where/why would one use something like that?*: I think it is used only for **obfuscation** :)

Comment: added [code] int *q = dos; [/code]and changed this [code] total += (datos [p]-avg) * (data [p +1]-avg);} so {total + = (data [q]-prom ) * (data [q +1]-avg);} but the error continues.
Specifically the error is shown in this line {total + = (data [p]-avg) * (data [p +1]-avg);}

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Hopefully you would never use it. It works because `x[y]` is by definition equivalent to `*(x+y)`, and addition is commutative (even for pointer+integer). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/827263); the accepted answer is massively upvoted, but [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18393343/827263) goes into the history.

Comment: Thanks for the history. Very interesting.

Comment: @modchan Why did you change the question into something totally different? All the answers look like complete gibberish now.

Comment: @MrLister, well, because 'data' and 'average' makes more sense for non-Spanish speakers. However, changed identifiers back (peer review pending), so answers are not so gibberish now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p` is a pointer to a float. That's why you're getting the error.

```
float *p, total;

...

total += (datos[p]-prom)*(datos[p+1]-prom);
```

You can only use `ints` as array indices in C.

Comment: aded `int *q = datos` and changed `total += (datos[p]-prom)*(datos[p+1]-prom);` for `total += (datos[q]-prom)*(datos[q+1]-prom);` but the error still appears and specifically on the line `total += (datos[q]-prom)*(datos[q+1]-prom);`

Comment: `q` is not an `int` -- it is an `int*`. Once again, you can only have `int` values as array subscripts. If you want to use `q` as your index, you will need to dereference it first with `*q`.

Comment: What can I do, when I need do this:

`double array[1000000000];

for(double i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
              array[i] = i;`

So, int dont have number as 1000000000. How can I iterate throught this array?

Answer (score 3):

Array subscripts must be an integer, an `int` type. You can't use any other type as array subscript. `p` is declared as `float *p`, i.e, a pointer to `float`. You can't use a pointer as array indices.

Comment: aded `int *q = datos` and changed `total += (datos[p]-prom)*(datos[p+1]-prom);` for `total += (datos[q]-prom)*(datos[q+1]-prom);` but the error still appears and specifically on the line `total += (datos[q]-prom)*(datos[q+1]-prom);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an int:

```
int p = 0;
...
while (p<n) {
    // rest is the same
```

or, you can use `p` as a pointer directly, which is, I suppose, what you intended.

```
while(p<datos+n) {
    total += (*p-prom)*(*(p+1)-prom);
```

Note, however, that you never increment `p`, so the loop will never end. Also, you never initialise `total`, so the result will be a random garbage value.

Answer (score 2):

C11dr 6.5.2.1 **Array subscripting** ... "One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object *type*’’, the other expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘*type*’’." ...

With `[]`, you get to do:

```
// pointer_type[integer_type]
float data[];
int n;
float total;
total = data[n];

// or the unconventional equivalent
// integer_type[pointer_type]
total = n[data];  // But let's leave that for another post

// Instead the OP did
// pointer_type[pointer_type]
// and received error: "Array subscript is not an integer"
float *p;
total = data[p];
```

The usage of `float` is not the issue here, but the usage of a pointer.

An integer type includes types `int`, `unsigned`, `size_t`, `long`, etc.

---

I think the OP wanted the following (or something like this)

```
float deviation(float data[], int n) {
  if (i <= 0) return 0;
  float data_average = average(data, n);
  float total = 0.0;  // don't forget to set to 0.0
  float *p = data;

  while (p < (data + n)) {
    total += (*p - data_average) * (*p - data_average);
    p++;
    }
  return sqrt(total / n);  // div by 0 averted
}
```